# Push notifications using rabbitmq

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I want to send notifications to mobile application using rabbitmq, the problem is that i never used amqp protocol, so i need some advices

1) As i read from here http://www.rabbitmq.com/alarms.html if i send message all cosumers will get it, do i need to create separate queue for each user?

2)I want to send push using GCM only when mobile application is turn off, can i do it using this structure(spring boot)?

```
@Controller
public class SampleController {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SampleController.class);

   @Autowired
    RabbitTemplate template;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    String home() {
        return "Empty mapping";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/process/{message}")
    @ResponseBody
    String error(@PathVariable("message") String message) {
        logger.info(String.format("Emit '%s'",message));
        String response = (String) template.convertSendAndReceive("query-example-2",message);
        logger.info(String.format("Received on producer '%s'",response));
        if(response==null) {
          sendPushViaGCM(message);
        }
        return String.valueOf("returned from worker : " + response);
    }
```

3) If mobile  appliction is turn off and i send push using gcm how to delete message from rabbitmq queue to avoid double push when application is turn on

4)As i suggested, when client connect to my rabbitmq service all others will don't have permission to listen other queues until first one  is not finished. Am i right?
Some code examples will be grateful

Comment: I want to use RabbitMQ and MQTT for push notification, did you implement this? how It's work ? any performance issue?

Comment: Yes I did so basically you have a service that listens for rabbit events
Then you push user id to rabbit and type of event, service gets message ,gets user's google id from db and sends notification using Firebase API

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to use google fcm, is it possible to use just mqtt and rabbitMq to implement push notification?

Comment: You can but it's not recommended,in order to do this you will have to make all your Android users as subscribers to the rabbit queue, also the subscription logic will be implemented in the app level which means that user has to open your app in order to see notifications, unfortunately only Google can send notifications and for you the only way to do it is to use what Google offers